# Can I forward all function parameters(same number,type and order) to another function

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass all the arguments that my function `print()` receives to a pre-existing function `sprintf()` to get the string i need

my current solution is to pass the parameters directly to `sprintf()` and get the `str` from it then sent it to `print()` but what I want to do is this:

```
void print("My age is %d",age){
   char str[100];
   sprintf(str,"My age is %d",age);  //pass all the parameter recived to sprintf
   //the rest of my code which will sent str to external pins of an MCU
}
```

Comment: If you want to get into it FreeRTOS has a cool minimal `printf` and `spintf` implementations. You could take a look at: https://github.com/atgreen/FreeRTOS/blob/master/Demo/CORTEX_STM32F103_Primer_GCC/printf-stdarg.c

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to implement [C's variable-length argument list](http://c-faq.com/varargs/) with something like:

```
int print(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    int     result;
    char   *str;

    va_start(arg, format);
    result = vasprintf(&str, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    /// Do something with str.

    return result;
}
```

Note: The `vasprintf()` function is a GNU extensions and is not available in C or POSIX. Yet, it's also available under *BSD. (Thanks @Ctx)

Comment: @Ctx My C is rusty. Should be okay now.

Comment: No problem ;) Yes, it's correct; however, it is worth mentioning that `vasprintf()` is a GNU extension and _GNU_SOURCE has to be defined to have it available.